# Dynamic current path in bash alias

Tags: bash, dynamic, path, alias

I'm using following bash alias on my dev computer :

```
alias lamp_perm="sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX $PWD && sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx $PWD"
```

It works well but only for the path I've opened my console : when changing dir, alias stays relative to start path.

[image: When changing dir, alias stays relative to start path]

I'd like that the alias change permissions for current path, how can I do that?

Thanks,

Ben.

Comment: for complex cases are _bash functions_ better as aliases.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead of `alias`:

```
unalias lamp_perm
lamp_perm () {
    sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX $PWD &&
    sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:$(whoami):rwx $PWD
}
```